# Low power microcontroller with gprs/gsm and maybe gps on board

Tags: gsm, gps, mkr-gsm-1400

Good day to ya all. I have a general question and a potential problem to solve.

My plan is to make a device which will work on 2 li-ion batteries. The purpose of this board is to take data from 3/4 sensors and send them via gprs to a server.( it would be ideal if it had gps on board also )

It must be small and it must at least hold half a year on those 2 ( at max 4 batteries ).

My question to you all is do you know a good low power microcontroller board with gsm/gprs chip on it (and maybe gps) ?

One solution would be to use a Arduino pro nano and a separate sim800 module and a separate gps module but this solution is just complicating. I need something with similar functionality of an Arduino and not so power hungry.

Hope to hear from you.

Comment: this is a Q&A site, not a brainstorming forum ... what is the actual arduino related problem that you are trying to solve? ... what is your question about the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Nothing to brainstorm here. Just asking is there some arduino or ATMega based board with gsm/gprs finctionality on it.

Comment: If someone helps than that is good. You as a senior member here dont have to be rude. If you can help than great. I know too that there probably is and that it is ATmega based. That is the reason i ask here and not my mother for it. Thanks <3

Comment: i do not mean to be rude and I apologize if you perceived it that way ... you asked for the existence of a component ... i said that it probably exists ... shopping questions are off topic here, so you cannot ask where to get one, but you can ask if one exists

Comment: Thanks for the apologize. I asked just for help if someone knows anything or has used something similar. Something to let me dig into just to set me on a right path.